# Convert mysql password hash string to mysql 8 password

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

After experimential migrate from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8, I noticed that mysql has changed password from mysql_native_password to caching_sha2_password. For some users, in the old database, the password hash string like

'*126CFB940B0843713B19A6C21B99C0F1F9F3AFB6'

is stored. Is it possible to convert this hashing to new caching_sha2_password?

PS: I know it is possible to let mysql use old mysql_native_password, but we prefer to follow up MySQL 8's suggestion to use caching_sha2_password.

Comment: This is Hashing.  For creating sha2_ you need  original password of native_password. If you try to convert Hash To Hash there should be loses. But I am not %100 sure.  As I know 
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password . But You said that you know this.

Comment: you need the original password. You can't convert hash to another hash. It'll consider hash is your original one.

Comment: Then the question is "How to alter existing user in order to use the new caching_sha2_password knowing the original password?", like giving an SQL script for example.